# SharePoint managed terms automatically updating other columns

Tags: managed-metadata

I have created a sharepoint list with managed terms in each column.  The first step determines the second step, the second step then determines the third and the third identifies the fourth.

Eg. Parts = wheels
            Doors

```
         Wheels = screws
                = Nuts

         Doors = window
               = Handles

                  Screws = long
                         = Short 

                  Nuts = round
                       = square
```

As each time I create a new item, all the selections will be made at the same time, rather than having to select one, and then selecting another, and then another, is there any way of selecting the very last one and it automatically filling in the previous information as it already knows what I've selected to get to there? Showing the full path looks messy and can be long in some cases, it would be helpful if it could auto fill in the information for me. Or should I not be using managed terms, is there a better way to do this?